# sw-precache-webpack-plugin on windows - cannot resolve window

Tags: webpack, service-worker

First time building a PWA, using `Laravel 5.8` + `Homestead`. I am getting the following error when page loads:

```
app.js:42706 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
ServiceWorker registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

And the error line in my app.js is:

```
window._ = __webpack_require__(/*! lodash */ "./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js");
```

The worker cached `app.js` cannot resolve the `window` constant.

I have set up `sw-precache-webpack-plugin`, so my `webpack.mix.js` is:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');

mix.js('resources/js/custom/buildings.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/custom/home.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    })
    .webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
            cacheId: 'sccpwa',
            filename: 'service-worker.js',
            staticFileGlobs: ['public/**/*.{css,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,js,html}'],
            minify: true,
            stripPrefix: 'public/',
            handleFetch: true,
            dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
                '/': ['resources/views/auth/login.blade.php'],
                '/building/list': ['resources/views/pages/building.blade.php'],
                '/home': ['resources/views/pages/home.blade.php'],
            },
            staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /mix-manifest\.json$/, /manifest\.json$/, /service-worker\.js$/],
            navigateFallback: '/',
            runtimeCaching: [
                {
                    urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\//,
                    handler: 'cacheFirst'
                },
                {
                    urlPattern: /^https:\/\/www\.projecturl\.com\/img\/(\w+)\.jpg/,
                    handler: 'cacheFirst'
                }
            ],
            importScripts: [
                './js/app.js',
                './js/buildings.js',
                './js/home.js'
            ]
        })
    ]
});
```

I then added this to register the service worker at the top of my `app.js`

```
require('./app-bootstrap');

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator ) {        
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            // Registration was successful
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
            // registration failed :(
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() { .APP JS STUFF HERE. };
```

`npm` compiles it with no errors and I can see the `addEventListener` being executed, but then the above error pops.

What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a very simple mistake. You're importing (importScript) your application code into the SW script. When it tries to execute, the error happens.

Service Worker execution context is different from the usual page execution context. You cannot execute 1:1 your app code in the SW. It usually wouldn't even make any sense.

I'm mostly sure you've understood the importScripts parameter in the workbox config wrong. It means: import these scripts into the SW and execute them.

Comment: Hi @pate thanks. But commenting our the importScripts also does not solve the issue as the pages cached come with the same scripts and fail at 'document.getelementById'. Is there an example you can point me to to offliine / cached js for pwa? Thanks.